# Detect browser ClickOnce support with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clickonce

I see that ClickOnce is still supported by Microsoft in Visual Studio 2019 / .NET 5/6.

But installing from the web page is only supported with IE, Edge (not Chromium, where is is disabled by default), or Firefox and Chrome with an unofficial plugin...

Is there a way, with JavaScript, to detect if the current browser support ClickOnce or not ?

Comment: [Nothing here?](https://www.google.com/search?q=ClickOnce+microsoft+detect)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hover the tag